# How can I get image from Profile model into my Post model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two models `Profile` and `Post`. I need to access an image from `Profile` model to `Post` model. How to do it ?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image =  models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    #Some other fields

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Some other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `Post` object you want to render to the context you can render the image of the post author of `post` with:

```
<img src="{{ post.user.profile.image.url }}">
```